# Symfony: Generically Find Out If Current Request Is Login Request

Tags: php, symfony, authentication

Is there a **generic** way in Symfony (version 3 or 4) of finding out **whether the current request is a login request or not**? I mean actually generic, independent of whether the developer uses form login, basic auth, Guard Authenticator, etc.

More specifically, I want to distinguish between a login request and any other request inside a `kernel.request` and a `kernel.response` event. I get the route like so:

```
public function onKernelResponse(FilterResponseEvent $event): void
{
    $request = $event->getRequest();
    $route = $request->attributes->get('_route');
}
```

The thing is: The Guard Authenticator does not listen to a specific route nor do I have the possibility to configure a specific one. [`form_login` does have a `check_path`](https://symfony.com/doc/current/security/form_login_setup.html), but it depends on the method.

**So: Is there a generic way?**

Comment: Considering that HTTP Basic Auth isn’t an actual “login”, there won’t be any “login request” either in that case ... so not sure what you’d actually want to detect in that case to begin with.

Comment: I suppose to think about security.interactive_login and security.authentication.failure. May be this will help you: http://www.webtipblog.com/create-authentication-listener-symfony-2/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is no "standard way', because there is not quite a standard "login request":

- on a Form login, you are requesting the `check_path` (note: that can be a route)
- on a HTTP Basic Auth, any request have credentials attached (as noted by @CBroe)
- the same for (basic) API keys
- using Guard, you are free to do virtually anything!

So instead, you can either check you are on a specific path/route, either you can check if user is not granted `IS_AUTHENTICATED_REMEMBERED` role, as login and login check pages are open to anonymous users (though all users get `IS_AUTHENTICATED_ANONYMOUS` role).